# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate nested not updating object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering why:

```js
const props = {
    excluded: true
}
const image = await Image.findByIdAndUpdate(
    imageId, {
        $set: 'image.ingest': props
    }, {
        new: true
    }
)
```

Doesn't update the image document with the `excluded` field whereas:

```
const props = {
    excluded: true
}
const image = await Image.findById(imageId);

image.ingest = {
    ...image.ingest,
    ...props
};

await image.save();
```

does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you forgot to use `{ }` after `$set`. Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aI7-CLnrA5V).

Also, checked using `mongoose` this query and works fine:

```js
var updated = await model.findByIdAndUpdate(id,
{
  "$set":{
    "image.ingest":"new value"
  }
},{
  "new":true
})
```